# PHP mssql displaying column does not work

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, iis

So I have this odd issue I have a table with a bunch of values and column when I run my query in sql studio it works but when I goto display my table on my site when it gets to the date column it doesn't display it and it only diplays one record even if there are many now im not sure why it's doing this the query works. It does this for any date column of any table in this database. I am using MSSQL 2008 with iis and php here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<?php
echo "Door 1 Current State= Closed<br />";
echo "Door 2 Current State= Closed<br />";
echo "Door 3 Current State= Closed<br />";
echo "Door 4 Current State= Closed<br />";
echo "state1= Green State0 = Yellow state84=red stateA0 = Red state3=green<br />";
require('connection.php');


$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.v_records";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die (sqlsrv_errors());  
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result))
{ 
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Card</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Dorr</th>
<th>Reader</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>State</th>
</tr>";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Card'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ReaderN'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ReaderNo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";  
  echo "<td>" . $row['Warn'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
}

else
{echo "No results were found.<br />";}


/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

I added this to the loop SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC but it did not fix the issue. I tried creating a view and giving an alias to the column but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop like this:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
//...
```